# How does Array.from work on objects?

Tags: javascript

I have the following function:

```
getitem = (count) => Array.from({ length: count }, (v, k) => k)
```

Now when i use this function like so:

```
getitem(10) // result ::- (10) [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

As you can see above , i get an array of ten items, i am not sure how this happened , How exactly is `Array.from` working on an object ?

Even after refering [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) i am a bit confused.

So how does Array.From create an array of 10 elements when passed an object with length: 10 ?

Comment: MSN mentions that `arrayLike` mean  "array-like objects (objects with a length property"

Comment: But he simply quoted the MDN page you said you read?

Comment: :) sometimes different context helps…

Comment: Oh well, i guess that's right :)